# VBA Web Scraper For Loop to Input Data from Excel Column C is Giving Run-time error '438': Object Doesn't Support This Property or Method

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, web-scraping, range

I am very new to VBA and as this is a work computer, I cannot use anything like Selenium.  The purpose of my macro is to generate work reports from a vendor based application (the data is stored on my company's servers) for my boss.  I have removed a lot of my code that works as some contains confidential information.

I am trying to use a For loop to input IDs into the search box to take me to the pages I need to scrape data from.  The IDs are listed in Column C of a sheet called "Data2".  I basically need it to go into a search box and then hit a button.

My VBA:

```
Sub D_Scrape()

'Declare variables
Dim url As String
Dim browser As InternetExplorerMedium
Dim htmlDoc As Object
Dim cCoEnter As Object
Dim sButton As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim lRow As Long
Dim td As Object
Dim tr As Object

'Initialize variables
url = 'unable to share this
Set ws = Worksheets("Data2")

'Initialize IE & Set Visibility
Set browser = New InternetExplorerMedium
browser.Visible = True
browser.navigate url

'Set document referencefi
Set htmlDoc = browser.document 

'Enter Collection into Search box in collection
Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 8))
lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
Set cCoEnter = htmlDoc.getElementsByName("collectionSearchBox:collectionSearchTxt")

For i = 2 To lRow
     cCoEnter.Value = ws.Range("C" & i).Value

htmlDoc.getElementsByName("collectionSearchBox:collectionSearchBtn").Item.Click

'Get Mileage
Set tr = htmlDoc
Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1))
For each td in tr.getElementsByName("collectionInfoBox;SummaryInformationBox:milesTraveled")
     ws.Range("K" & i).Value = td.getAttribute("value")
Next
Next i

End Sub
```

The HTML applicable to this is:

```
<tr align="left">

<td align="left" width="15%"><label>ID:</label></td>

<td align="left" width="15%" name="collectionSearchBox:collectionSearchTxt" type="text" value=""/></td>

<td align="left"><input name="collectionSearchBox:collectionSearchBtn"/></td>

</tr>
```

My Excel:

[image: Excel Screenshot]

I had looked at several posts as to how to specify a range that is dynamic (some months there will be hundreds I'll need to generate the report for and other months considerably less).

I am getting a Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method on the line
`cCoEnter.Value = ws.Range("C" & i).Value`

I have tried using a variable for the range set to `ws.Range("C1:C" & lRow)` but it didn't make a difference still getting the 438 error on the `cCoEnter.Value = ws.Range("C" & i).Value`.

No value is entered in the ID box.

I am very unsure of what else to try and would appreciate any suggestions.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just like before, divide and conquer.  Can you echo the value of `ws.Range("C"&i).Value`?  If you echo the value of `cCoEnter`, what do you see?

Comment: I have tried to set the cCoEnter value to one of the column C cells directly (both a singe and a range "C2:C16") and I am still getting the error.  I don't see any typos in my variables.

Comment: _getElementsByName_ returns a collection of elements. To which of these elements do you wanna assign a value (or compare)?

Comment: To answer how to value the input text use this constructor `cCoEnter.Item.innerText = ws.Range("C" & i).Value`.  You should be able to capture the sButton object outside of the loop, and then execute the click of that inside the loop.  You have an inspector tool available as you step through your code that lets you see what  you have captured.  It could be "nothing", which means it is not configured right, or some object that you can expand and see what attributes are available.  Under the Debug menu is Add Watch. Select the object in your code and then click on Add Watch.

Comment: I changed the value to cCoEnter.Item.innerText = ws.Range("C" & i).Value and the first time I ran the code, it put in the first ID number and clicked.  It then stopped.  I ran it again and it put in the last ID and clicked.  Now it just defaults to the last ID on the list.

Comment: I have played around with it and added back in one of the elements I'm scraping (code added above.  So long as I have an application.Wait, it will pull the first value of mileage then give a run-time error '70':  Permission denied on the "cCoEnter.Item.innerText=ws.Range("C" & i).Value line.  If I don't have the application wait there, it cycles through too fast and simply puts 0's for all the rows in column K.

Comment: Does the web page reload on the click?  If so, then your htmlDoc no longer represents what is loaded.  You may need to update htmlDoc after each click.

Comment: I will have to give that a try.  Short term, I found a work around where I am utilizing a drop down menu that takes me to a different screen where I can input the ID and search.  I was hoping to use the search box in each "collection" to save time, but am up against a deadline.  I will try updating the htmlDoc after each click and hopefully that will work.

Comment: I updated the htmDoc in the loop.  Still gave the permission denied.  I moved the set ws = Sheets("Data2") into the loop and I am not getting an error but it is also not putting any values in the search box.